# Display the state information to a list of participants dynamically

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, slack, corda, discourse

I have tweeked the Yo- CordApp to send to a list of participants instead of single participant in the target. I would like to send the YO to more than one Party, moreover I just want to display the state information to the parties which does not require the signatures of all parties. But I am  stuck with the below error. Please help.

```
FlowLogicRef cannot be constructed for FlowLogic of type net.corda.yo.YoFlow as could not find matching constructor for: {target=null}
```

The link to my code: https://github.com/ToniyaSundaram/CordaProjects.

Comment: Are you interacting with the CorDapp via the API? What URL are you visiting to get the exception above?

Comment: I am using Postman to interact. This is the  'URL: localhost:10007/api/yo/yo?target=PartyB and localhost:10007/api/yo/yo?target=PartyB&target=BidderC'. I also want to know is it possible to skip "collecting signatures from other parties" part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in your API endpoint code.

You set:

```
val acceptors : ArrayList<Party>? = null;
```

And then in the subsequent loop, you have the following logic for expanding the array:

```
if (acceptors != null) {
    acceptors.add(to)
}
```

Since `acceptors` is initialised to `null`, this condition is never true and you never expand the list. As a result, when you try to construct the `YoFlow`, you are trying to set the `target` parameter to `null`, which isn't allowed due to Kotlin's null safety.

Try this instead:

```
val acceptors = mutableListOf<Party>()
```

Re: your comment, you have to collect the signatures of any required signers listed on the commands, or your transaction will be considered invalid.